# How can I use Conda environments with RStudio Server?

Tags: r, conda, rstudio-server

For my data science projects, I use `conda` to keep track of all installed packages.

```
> conda create -n my_project R=3.4.1 r-tidyverse
> conda activate my_project
> which R 
/storage/apps/anaconda3/envs/my_project/bin/R
> R --version
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) -- "Single Candle"
```

How can I use the Conda environment's R within `rstudio-server`?
I am aware of the [`rsession-which-r`](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552316-Configuring-the-Server) configuration option, but like that I cannot easily switch between environments.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**I created a GitHub repository containing two scripts that allow you to start Rstudio server in non-daemonized mode from within a Conda environment: [rstudio-server-conda](https://github.com/grst/rstudio-server-conda).**

### How it works:

You can start rstudio-server in the non-daemonized mode (similar to `jupyter notebook`) from within a
Conda environment.

```
> conda activate my_project
> /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver \
   --server-daemonize=0 \
   --www-port 8787 \
   --rsession-which-r=$(which R) \
   --rsession-ld-library-path=$CONDA_PREFIX/lib
```

To avoid additional problems with library paths, also `rsession` needs to run within the Conda environment. This is achieved by wrapping rsession into the rsession.sh script. The path to the wrapped rsession executable can be passed to rserver as command line argument.

```
rserver # ...
    --rsession-path=rsession.sh
```

Finally, when using multiple users a unique `secret-cookie-key` has to be generated for each user. The path to the secret cookie key can be passed to rserver as a command line parameter.

```
uuid > /tmp/rstudio-server/${USER}_secure-cookie-key
rserver # ...
   --secure-cookie-key-file /tmp/rstudio-server/${USER}_secure-cookie-key
```

Comment: Great answer! Although I'd set the `www-port` to `8787` instead, the default port for rstudio-server.
Setting [rsession-which-r ](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552316-Configuring-the-Server) to the R executable within a Conda environment kept giving me initialization errors.

Using your answer I can now run rstudio-server within a Conda environment that will also correctly use the Python environment to use with the `reticulate` package.

Comment: Thanks, using the --secure-cookie-key-file option fixed an issue with running rocker/tidyverse via singularity on a multi-user cluster where rserver would exit with:

`ERROR system error 2 (No such file or directory) [path=/tmp/rstudio-server/secure-cookie-key]; OCCURRED AT: rstudio::core:: <snip>`