# How to use Rstudio installed on server to connect to r_env created by Conda?

Tags: r, conda, rstudio-server

We have Rstudio installed on our Linux server to which I do not have admin access. However, on the same server, I have Conda installed and used it to create an R environment named **r_env**.

How do I use the **r_env** created by Conda in the Rstudio to which I don't have admin rights?

Comment: Have you tried launching RStudio Server after activating the environment? i.e., similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62737170/570918

Comment: @merv, generally, RStudio Server launches as a stand-alone page. I am not sure how to activate the conda environment before launching it.  Do you have any idea?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52381661/how-can-i-use-conda-environments-with-rstudio-server but this seems to need admin rights. Kind of implies the answer is: *you can't*.